# What model(s) are appropriate for unbounded species abundance data with 0's and environmental response variables in R?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, ecology

I am conducting a research project on the vegetation composition of an abandoned mine site to determine the environmental factors that influence species abundance (cover) and composition.

Study Design: I have 10 sites, within each site 10 randomly placed 1x1m quadrats were sampled for plant species percent cover (abundance) along with a soil sample that was tested for heavy metals concentration(Pb, As, Cu, Zn), pH, NPK, and OM. Factors such as slope, aspect were also recorded.

Analysis: From species abundance data I created the response variables: **total cover, exotic cover, native cover, and species richness**. I would like to investigate if my environmental variables are influencing the response variables I described above. I have tried using `lm` in R but my response variables are not normally distributed and therefore I believe violate the assumptions of linear modeling. I have also tried `glm` but since my cover abundance data contains many 0's and is not bounded at 100%, as there can be more than 100% cover in a quadrat, I don't think any of the error distribution families of `glm` can accommodate this.

So, I would appreciate any input on selecting an appropriate model for my response variables. If possible I would like to see the size of the effect or r2 rather than just a P value. Thank you very much for your time. If you would be interested in the data I could provide it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Questions about code are off topic here, which is probably why your question has close votes. I think your question is more about statistics, so I am voting to leave it open, but you might want to make it clear you are interested in statistics, not code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to transform your responses.

If it is continuous and right skeewed, try a cube root transformation since it deals with zeros.
Otherwise, check if the species abundance in counts are hightly correlated with their cover %, if they are, you can try a count distribution family, such as poisson or negative binomial in case of overdispersion.

How is it possible to have a cover greater than 100%? (curiosity)

Another detail, are you inspecting for normality in the model residuals or at response variable itself?

You should inspect for normality at the model residuals, such as:

```
plot(model) #residuals versus fitted should show homocedasticity
hist(resid(model)) #should looks like a bell shape
shapiro.test(resid(model)) # not significative= normality
```

Since your quadrats are nested in site (non indenpendence-pseudoreplication), it is worth to consider a mixed modeling approach, where you should use sites as random factors.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! To answer your question about cover, in my study you can have different layers of cover so maybe a shrub covers 100% of the quadrat but has an herb growing beneath it, the cover will be >100%.

Comment: Also, species counts are not correlated with cover% so I can't use that.  As for inspecting normality, I am looking at both, my response variables are left skewed and when using untransformed they don't make pretty residual graphs.  I will take a look at mixed modeling approach!

Comment: http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/t/transint.html take a look at this.

Comment: Since you are more interested in r2 rather than p values, may it is worth to use a random forest algorithm, which gives variables importance and do not make distribution assumptions

Answer (score 1):

First, ordinary least squares regression does not make assumptions about the distribution of the variables, only about the errors - estimated by the residuals.

Second, assuming that your residuals are not normal, then, rather than transforming your variable, I suggest you use a method that makes fewer assumptions. One such is quantile regression - I have done a lot of this, but in SAS, not R, but there is an R package `quantreg` that may help.  Quantile regression makes no assumptions about the residuals.